# Youtu.be URLs no longer equivalent with youtube.com URLs

Tags: youtube, short-url

I have made about 20 YouTube videos each producing an URL on the form `www.youtu.be/…` that was equivalent to the same URL but with `www.youtube.com/…`.

I produced QR codes based on the former URLs and have published these in my book which was published last autumn (Oct 2012). Now the youtu.be URLs no longer work (why??), but the similar youtube.com URLs are OK.

How can I make the youtu.be URLs work again (otherwise I would have to produce new QR codes, which is problematic as the other ones are published in a book).

Answer (score 1):

If you still having this problem I suggest that your QRcode will be to a site that you own and this sith will redirect to the videos. this way even if youtube will kick your videos out you will be able to upload them to other server and just update the rediriction